# How to unlock a node in Jackrabbit held by Open-scoped Locks?

Tags: java, jackrabbit

I have locked a node using the below code

```
ocm.lock("/path1", true, true);
```

Here the 3rd argument is true which states that it is a `Open-scoped Locks.`

And it is successfully locked.

But now i am writing a new Java Program to unlock a node.

```
boolean b1 = ocm.isLocked("/path1");
System.out.println(b1);                      // RETURNS TRUE.
Node n = session.getNode("/path1");
Lock l = n.getLock();
ocm.unlock("/path1", l.getLockToken());
```

But i am getting a exception here. And it is not unlocking the node.

```
ERROR [main] ObjectContentManagerImpl.java:957 Cannot unlock path: /path1 Jcr user: admin has no lock token to do this. Lock was placed with user: admin
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.exception.IllegalUnlockException
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.manager.impl.ObjectContentManagerImpl.unlock(ObjectContentManagerImpl.java:958)
    at ocm.UnlockNode.main(UnlockNode.java:36)
```

How i can unlock the node?

My `UnlockNode.java` code.

```
Repository repository = new URLRemoteRepository("http://localhost:8083/rmi");
Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin","admin".toCharArray()));
Mapper mapper = new AnnotationMapperImpl(classes);
ObjectContentManager ocm = new ObjectContentManagerImpl(session, mapper);

LockManager lm = session.getWorkspace().getLockManager();
lm.addLockToken("a096a79c-5edf-4a17-baa4-aba01f8013d8-J");
boolean b1 = ocm.isLocked("/path1");
System.out.println(b1);
try {
    ocm.unlock("/path1","a096a79c-5edf-4a17-baa4-aba01f8013d8-J");
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could paste the exception as well...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to get the lock from another session...

> java.lang.String getLockToken()
>
> May return the lock token for this
>   lock. If this lock is open-scoped and the current session either holds
>   the lock token for this lock, or the repository chooses to expose the
>   lock token to the current session, then this method will return that
>   lock token. Otherwise this method will return null.

Either get the lock token, after locking, and store it for later or write your own LockManager with a checkUnlock() method that does what you want it to.

Comment: I am able to get lock token now but now it is giving different exception .I have pasted that in question.

Comment: Have you added the lock token to your new admin session? Once you have your session do lockManager.addLockToken(lockToken)

Comment: Still not solve .Please check my whole code. Updated the question.

Comment: You really shouldnt hard code the lock token. You can't be sure its the right one.